# Конфликт bootstrap.js и yii

Tags: jquery, javascript, yii, bootstrap, yii-bootstrap

Обнаружил вот такой конфликт между скриптами bootstrap и фреймворка yii.
При добавлении шаблона и скриптов в yii:

```
<script src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

в DOM появляется файл:

```
<script src="/assets/25b4e139/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js" type="text/javascript">
```

который работает только после удаления `bootstrap.min.js`. Скажите, кто знает, как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2):

`jquery.yiigridview.js` - это скрипт для работы CGridView, опубликованный как ресурс.

Попробуй подключить бутстрап так:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl."/js/bootstrap.min.js", CClientScript::POS_HEAD);
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вам.